# Elliptic functions (in particular, the Weierstrass P-function) to solve ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

I have the following ODE

$$-\frac{vf^2}{2} = \frac{(f')^2}{2} + 2f^3 + Cf + D,$$

where $v, C, D$ are constants.

I've been given the hint to use elliptic functions (in particular, the Weierstrass P-function). I've looked at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) for it, but really can't see how it can be of use.

Any help/hints?

Answer (score 3):

HINT.-Clearly first you should know well the $\wp_L(z)$ for the lattice $L$. It is defined by

$$\wp(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\omega\in L - \{0\}}\big [\frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2}-\frac{1}{\omega^2}\big ]$$ and an important algebraic relation between the trascendental funtions $\wp$ and $\wp'$ is $$(\wp')^2=4(\wp)^3-g_2\wp-g_3\qquad (*)$$ where the called invariants of $\wp$, $g_2$ and $g_3$ are defined by
$$g_2=60\sum_{\omega\in L - \{0\}}\frac{1}{\omega^4}\\g_3=140\sum_{\omega\in L - \{0\}}\frac{1}{\omega^6}\\$$ Now your equation has the form
$$(f')^2=4(-f)^3-vf^2-2Cf-2D\qquad (**)$$

Try to associate the relations $(*)$ and $(**)$ in such a way that $f(x)=\wp'(t)$ and $x=\wp(t)$. You have to construct a lattice with $v,C,D$ and satisfying $C^3-27D^2\ne 0$. You can discard the term $vf^2$ in $(**)$ like as usual for solving the cubic equation (*for a beginner all this it is not easy at all*).

Comment: Thanks for your insight - ok, it looks like this may be too advanced for me at the moment!